# Linux iptables allow some ports

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

We have a Linux server (CentOS 6.3), where all ports seem to be accessible from inside (when tried from the server), but only SSH is accessible from outside. I would like to allow some other ports, such as 1521 (Oracle), but I cannot get it working.

I tried the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

but I still get a "Connection timed out" when I do a "telnet 192.168.97.1 1521" from another machine, while I can connect from the server with the same command.

This is what I have in /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Mar 15 12:13:41 2013
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:1136]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [14:878]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [15:986]
-A POSTROUTING -o em1 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 15 12:13:41 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Mar 15 12:13:41 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [45:3812]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 15 12:13:41 2013
```

(The line -A POSTROUTING -o em1 -j MASQUERADE is there because previously I also tried to install a PPTP server as described [here](http://blog.secaserver.com/2011/10/install-vpn-pptp-server-centos-6/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which the directives appear is important. The first match wins.

So your problem is:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
```

Thus you never allow traffic to port 1521.

To fix the problem, simply reverse the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following 2 options:
( I assume that you use Red Hat or CentOS Linux).

***Option 1:***
In a root shell execute the command:

```
iptables -L --line-numbers
```

That will show you the chains and the rules that are applied in each chain with line numbers. For example, in one of my servers the output is:

```
iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
3    ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
4    ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
5    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
6    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp    dpt:snmp
....
14   DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

So, in order to setup your rule, I would execute the following commands:

```
iptables -I 7 INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Using the **-I 7** instead of the -A I instructed iptables to add a new rule at line 7, and push down all other rules.
Note that in my case I could use any line number from 7-14.

---

***Option 2:***

Edit the file **/etc/sysconfig/iptables**, find the last entry before the "DROP" and add the rule there, save the file and reload iptables.